# Detecting multiple objects using openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, pattern-matching

I'm trying to develop a code which recognizes two different patterns. I have trained both the patterns separately and obtained the cascade XMLs of both. I give the patterns in a single image, which the program is supposed to detect.

How can I implement this using 'detectMultiScale' in openCV or are there any other option(s)??

Please help :)

PS: I'm using C++ in openCV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have trained the patterns seperately, you'll have to run `detectMultiScale()` twice.

Comment: got it.. :) It's working.. I used 2 xmls and wrote detectMultiScale twice.